# C Program Structures Using File Input And Output

Tags: c, file, loops, io, structure

First C programming class and beginning to learn programming. I am currently learning how to use file input/output in C and this is a learning task to help understand this process.

The task calls for the program to use the an input file with random U.S. addresses and then output the addresses in order from least to greatest by zipcode. As the program stands right now it does not crash, but I get an empty output file. I may have an idea of what is wrong. I believe that I have to tell the program/function when to start reading the input file, then when to write, and lastly when to close the file. Possibly use a 'while' statement somewhere?

What is needed and where to get this program to output the addresses into a file? Can anyone kindly recommend a function/statement that can be added in order to achieve this?

Thank you so very much in advance for your help, time, and guidance in getting this program working!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 32
#define STRUCT_SIZE 512

struct info {
    char name[BUFF_SIZE];
    char stAddress[BUFF_SIZE];
    char cityAndState[BUFF_SIZE];
    char zip[BUFF_SIZE];
};

void selectionSort(struct info *ptrStruct[], int size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fpin, *fpout;
    int count, size;
    char buffer[512];
    struct info *ptrStruct[STRUCT_SIZE];

    if (argc != 3) {

        printf("Usage: program, inputfile, outputfile\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {

        printf("Can't open input file\n");
        exit(1);

    }

    if ((fpout = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {

        printf("Can't open output file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (count = 0; count < STRUCT_SIZE; count++){
        ptrStruct[count] = (struct info*) malloc(sizeof(struct info));
        if (EOF == scanf("%599[^\n]%*c", buffer)){
            free(ptrStruct[count]);
            break;
        };
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->name, buffer);
        scanf("%511[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->stAddress, buffer);
        scanf("%511[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->cityAndState, buffer);
        scanf("%511[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->zip, buffer);
    }

    size = count;
    selectionSort(ptrStruct, size);

    printf("\n\nLEAST TO GREATEST\n");
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->name);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->stAddress);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->cityAndState);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->zip);
        free(ptrStruct[count]);
    }

fclose(fpin);
fclose(fpout);

}

void selectionSort(struct info *ptrStruct[], int size)
{
    int count1, count2;
    int minIndex;
    struct info *ptrTemporary;

    for (count2 = 0; count2 < size - 1; count2++)
    {
        minIndex = count2;
        for (count1 = count2 + 1; count1 < size; count1++)
        {
            if (strcmp(ptrStruct[count1]->zip, ptrStruct[minIndex]->zip) < 0)
                minIndex = count1;
        }
        if (minIndex != count2){
            ptrTemporary = ptrStruct[count2];
            ptrStruct[count2] = ptrStruct[minIndex];
            ptrStruct[minIndex] = ptrTemporary;
        }
    }
}
```

input used:

```
A1, A2
20294 Lorenzana Dr
Woodland Hills, CA
91364
B1, B2
19831 Henshaw St
Culver City, CA
94023
C1, C2
5142 Dumont Pl
Azusa, CA
91112
D1, D2
20636 De Forest St
Woodland Hills, CA
91364
A1, A2
20294 Lorenzana Dr
Woodland Hills, CA
91364
E1, E2
4851 Poe Ave
Woodland Hills, CA
91364
F1, F2
20225 Lorenzana Dr
Los Angeles, CA
91111
G1, G2
20253 Lorenzana Dr
Los Angeles, CA
90005
H1, H2
5241 Del Moreno Dr
Los Angeles, CA
91110
I1, I2
5332 Felice Pl
Stevenson Ranch, CA
94135
J1, J2
5135 Quakertown Ave
Thousand Oaks, CA
91362
K1, K2
720 Eucalyptus Ave 105
Inglewood, CA
89030
L1, L2
5021 Dumont Pl
Woodland Hills, CA
91364
M1, M2
4819 Quedo Pl
Westlake Village, CA
91362
I1, I2
5332 Felice Pl
Stevenson Ranch, CA
94135
I1, I2
5332 Felice Pl
Stevenson Ranch, CA
94135
N1, N2
20044 Wells Dr
Beverly Hills, CA
90210
O1, O2
7659 Mckinley Ave
Los Angeles, CA
90001
```

Comment: Won't the * in %*c suppress assigning the value to the buffer in the scanf call?

Comment: `"%599[^\n]%*c"` --> `"%511[^\n]%*c"`, `scanf` --> `fscanf`, `printf`-> `fprintf`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Thanks! I forgot to delete that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `main` is a function of type `int` and should `return` a value to the shell. While not mandatory in all cases, it is good practice to initialize ALL of your variables (especially when you are new to C).

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids `caMelCase` variables in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

Your read loop shows you are entirely confused about how to get your data from your input file into your program. You have a `BUFF_SIZE` constant of `32`, but apparently went back and hardcoded `buffer` at `512`, guessing that might help you get input into your program. (You cannot guess your way to a valid solution in C, ever...)

Your longest line of input is 22 chars, so `+1` for the `'\n'` and `+1` for the `'\0'` *nul-terminating* character means your longest line will require `24` chars for storage. That is more than covered with `BUFF_SIZE 32`.

Your input routine requires that you read one *line-at-a-time*. This is better done with a line oriented input function like `fgets` or `getline`. Further you need to insure *all 4 lines* that make up an address are read together and ALL successfully read or none of the data should be stored. (you don't want partial addresses stored). If you simply check each one and fail on any one (and continue the loop) your `name`, `address`, `citystate`, and `zip` will be out of sync for the next read.

The way you can accomplish this in a way that makes sense, is to use a static instance of your `info` struct to build each address in. Then, once all members contain a validated value, add that information to your pointer array.

For instance your read loop could be done something like the following:

```
for (idx = 0; idx < MAXS;) {
    int a1, a2, a3, a4;
    char buf[MAXB] = "";
    struct info tmp = { .name = "" };

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break; /* read/validate lines */
    a1 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') || 
           !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.name));

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break;
    a2 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') ||
          !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.address));

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break;
    a3 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') ||
          !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.citystate));

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break;
    a4 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') ||
          !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.zip));

    if (a1 || a2 || a3 || a4) continue; /* any error, skip all lines */

    if (!(addr[idx] = malloc (sizeof *addr[idx]))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* copy tmp to addr[idx] and increment index */
    memcpy (addr[idx++], &tmp, sizeof tmp);
}
```

(**note:** `buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n'` just checks (1) if `buf` is full, and (2) whether the character before the *nul-terminating* character is something other than a `'\n'` indicating a *short read* occurred and the number of characters in the line exceeded `MAXB` (your `BUFF_SIZE` -- I don't like to type))

As for your `FILE *` pointers, you only need a single `fp` pointer. (You never have more than one stream open at a time). As for the output function, if you think about it, you only need a single output function to handle output to both the terminal (e.g, `stdout` file stream) or to any file (e.g. `fp = fopen (somefile, "w")`). So you can simply create a single print function formatted however you would like it. For instance:

```
/** write 'n' addresses to FILE *fp */
void prnaddr (struct info **addr, int n, FILE *fp)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fprintf (fp, " %-8s    %-22s    %-20s    %s\n", addr[i]->name,
                addr[i]->address, addr[i]->citystate, addr[i]->zip);
}
```

That simply provides a sane single line output format, for example:

```
 K1, K2      720 Eucalyptus Ave 105    Inglewood, CA           89030
 O1, O2      7659 Mckinley Ave         Los Angeles, CA         90001
 G1, G2      20253 Lorenzana Dr        Los Angeles, CA         90005
```

Putting all the pieces together, and noting that when you need multiple constants declared, you can simply use a single global `enum` instead of multiple `#define` lines (and shortening the names of your constants to `MAXC` (max characters) and `MAXS` (max structs), you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXB = 32, MAXS = 512 };

struct info {
    char name[MAXB];
    char address[MAXB];
    char citystate[MAXB];
    char zip[MAXB];
};

void prnaddr (struct info **addr, int n, FILE *fp);
void selectionSort(struct info *addr[], int size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, idx = 0;
    struct info *addr[MAXS] = {NULL};
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: program, inputfile, outputfile\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (idx = 0; idx < MAXS;) {
        int a1, a2, a3, a4;
        char buf[MAXB] = "";
        struct info tmp = { .name = "" };

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break; /* read/validate lines */
        a1 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') || 
            !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.name));

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break;
        a2 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') ||
            !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.address));

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break;
        a3 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') ||
            !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.citystate));

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXB, fp)) break;
        a4 = ((buf[MAXB - 2] && buf[MAXB - 2] != '\n') ||
            !sscanf (buf, "%31[^\n]", tmp.zip));

        if (a1 || a2 || a3 || a4) continue; /* any error, skip all lines */

        if (!(addr[idx] = malloc (sizeof *addr[idx]))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        /* copy tmp to addr[idx] and increment index */
        memcpy (addr[idx++], &tmp, sizeof tmp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    selectionSort(addr, idx);

    printf("\nLEAST TO GREATEST\n");
    prnaddr (addr, idx, stdout);

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open output file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    prnaddr (addr, idx, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) free(addr[i]);

    return 0;
}

/** write 'n' addresses to FILE *fp */
void prnaddr (struct info **addr, int n, FILE *fp)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fprintf (fp, " %-8s    %-22s    %-20s    %s\n", addr[i]->name,
                addr[i]->address, addr[i]->citystate, addr[i]->zip);
}

void selectionSort(struct info *addr[], int size)
{
    int idx1, idx2;
    int minIndex;
    struct info *ptrTemporary;

    for (idx2 = 0; idx2 < size - 1; idx2++)
    {
        minIndex = idx2;
        for (idx1 = idx2 + 1; idx1 < size; idx1++)
        {
            if (strcmp(addr[idx1]->zip, addr[minIndex]->zip) < 0)
                minIndex = idx1;
        }
        if (minIndex != idx2){
            ptrTemporary = addr[idx2];
            addr[idx2] = addr[minIndex];
            addr[minIndex] = ptrTemporary;
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

The input file you provided was use.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structaddr dat/structaddr.txt dat/structaddrout.txt

LEAST TO GREATEST
 K1, K2      720 Eucalyptus Ave 105    Inglewood, CA           89030
 O1, O2      7659 Mckinley Ave         Los Angeles, CA         90001
 G1, G2      20253 Lorenzana Dr        Los Angeles, CA         90005
 N1, N2      20044 Wells Dr            Beverly Hills, CA       90210
 H1, H2      5241 Del Moreno Dr        Los Angeles, CA         91110
 F1, F2      20225 Lorenzana Dr        Los Angeles, CA         91111
 C1, C2      5142 Dumont Pl            Azusa, CA               91112
 J1, J2      5135 Quakertown Ave       Thousand Oaks, CA       91362
 M1, M2      4819 Quedo Pl             Westlake Village, CA    91362
 E1, E2      4851 Poe Ave              Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 A1, A2      20294 Lorenzana Dr        Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 L1, L2      5021 Dumont Pl            Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 A1, A2      20294 Lorenzana Dr        Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 D1, D2      20636 De Forest St        Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 B1, B2      19831 Henshaw St          Culver City, CA         94023
 I1, I2      5332 Felice Pl            Stevenson Ranch, CA     94135
 I1, I2      5332 Felice Pl            Stevenson Ranch, CA     94135
 I1, I2      5332 Felice Pl            Stevenson Ranch, CA     94135
```

**Output in File**

```
$ cat dat/structaddrout.txt
 K1, K2      720 Eucalyptus Ave 105    Inglewood, CA           89030
 O1, O2      7659 Mckinley Ave         Los Angeles, CA         90001
 G1, G2      20253 Lorenzana Dr        Los Angeles, CA         90005
 N1, N2      20044 Wells Dr            Beverly Hills, CA       90210
 H1, H2      5241 Del Moreno Dr        Los Angeles, CA         91110
 F1, F2      20225 Lorenzana Dr        Los Angeles, CA         91111
 C1, C2      5142 Dumont Pl            Azusa, CA               91112
 J1, J2      5135 Quakertown Ave       Thousand Oaks, CA       91362
 M1, M2      4819 Quedo Pl             Westlake Village, CA    91362
 E1, E2      4851 Poe Ave              Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 A1, A2      20294 Lorenzana Dr        Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 L1, L2      5021 Dumont Pl            Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 A1, A2      20294 Lorenzana Dr        Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 D1, D2      20636 De Forest St        Woodland Hills, CA      91364
 B1, B2      19831 Henshaw St          Culver City, CA         94023
 I1, I2      5332 Felice Pl            Stevenson Ranch, CA     94135
 I1, I2      5332 Felice Pl            Stevenson Ranch, CA     94135
 I1, I2      5332 Felice Pl            Stevenson Ranch, CA     94135
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can see that you are scanning the data from the `buffer` variable using `scanf`. I can at least find the following errors in your code:

1. You should use `fscanf` to read from the file `fpin`.
2. Your problem lies in the `scanf` (`fscanf`) format specification also.
3. Also, while `scanf`-ing, I can see that you are scanning 599 characters into the `buffer` variable which is only of length 512. This has undefined behaviour.

One Solution: You should rather read the contents one record at a time and line by line.